# Pop up div form using a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following line of code :

```
<?php foreach($prescription as $process){?>

      <button id="issue"> <?php echo $process['medname'];?> </button>



        <?php }?>
```

On the click of the button , the following div form should pop up

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>phamarcy/issues" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Batch Number</th>

               <th>Quantity Requested </th>
               <th>Selling Price (Kshs:)</th>
               <th>Patients Name</th>
               <th>Requested  By</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><select name="item_id" onChange="ChooseContact(this)"id="drug_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach($prescription as $drugs){?>    
   <option value="<?php echo $drugs['medname']."|".$drugs['total_quantity']."|".$drugs['expiry_date']."|".$drugs['selling_mark_up_price']."|".$drugs['amount']."|".$drugs['Patients_Name']."|".$drugs['unit_cost']?>"><?php echo $drugs['batch_number']?></option>

    <?php }?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <input type="text" name="batch_number" id="batch_number" value="" size="1" />
    <input type="text" name="item_id" id="item_id" value="" size="1" />
    <input type="text" name="opening_bal" id="opening_bal" value="">
    <td><input type="text" name="batch_no" id="batch_no" value="" size="1" disabled="disabled"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="exp_date" id="exp_date" value=""  size="1" disabled="disabled"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="opening" id="opening" value="" size="1" disabled="disabled" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="issues" id="issues" value="" size="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="closing_bal" id="closing_bal" value=""  size="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="service" id="service" value="" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="hidden" name="service_point" id="service_point" value=""/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Issue">
    </td>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
```

From the following script which is supposed to open the  above div with the details :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 1600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
    },
    close: function() {
    //allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
    });
    $( ".issue" )
    .button()
    .click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
    });
    </script>
```

When I try to click on the button, there is no response. Is there a way how I can make a button pop up when clicked with php data in it?

Comment: You cannot create multiple buttons with the same id. Try changing that to class="issue" and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any element with class="issue"
Add that class to the element you want to fire the click event. 
also, i think you should remove .button()

```
$( ".issue" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```